# How to eage load many rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, orm, eloquent, eager-loading

Some ORMs like Laravel Eloquent load the relations of all the set's models by just one query. For example if there are 5 A models and these models have many B models, then just one query is performed for getting all the related B rows for all the A models.

I know that Relational Databases like MySQL do no return query results as an array. The only thing that I can think of for doing this, is getting all the matching B rows for all the A models and then grouping them manually for each model by the programming language being used. Is this correct? How the eager-loading is done?

P.S.: I know I can/should reverse-engineer the ORMs' code-base but it takes a lot of time!

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Just `INNER JOIN` for all the cases? I know ORMs are complex, but how the grouping of all the related rows/models is done? There should be an identifier for each relation in the query results so we can use it as the grouping criterion. My main question is: do they group the matching B rows for each A model manually (by iterating through the results) based on the joining/relation parameters? - I know you know SQL very well and you may not like ORMs, but that's a different topic.